# Brain storm: How to arrange DateTime to particular interval frame?

Tags: c#, algorithm, datetime, linear-algebra, algebra

Suppose i have a DateTime, e. g. 2010.12.27 12:33:58 and i have an interval frames of, suppose, 2 seconds, excluding the last border.

So, i have the following frames:

12:33:58(incl.)-12:34:00(excl.) - let it be interval 1

12:34:00(incl.)-12:34:02(excl.) - let it be interval 2

12:34:02(incl.)-12:34:04(excl.) - let it be interval 3

and so on.

I'm given a random DateTime value and i have to correlate that value according the above rules.

E. g. the value "12:33:58" falls into interval 1, "12:33:59" falls into interval 1, "12:34:00" falls into interval 2 and so on.

In code it should look like the following:

```
var dt = DateTime.Now;
DateTime intervalStart = apply_the_algorythm(dt);
```

It seems to be some simple arithmetic action(s) with float or something, any decisions are welcome!

Comment: What did you come up with so far?

Comment: I'm writing High-Frequency Trading system and i need a fast algorythm to arrange deals into japanese candles

Answer (score 2):

If the interval is only second resolution and always divided 86400, then take the number of seconds that have passed today, divide it by the interval, round it to an integer value, multiply it, and add it back to today. Something like dateinquestion.Subtract(dateinquestion.Date).TotalSeconds, ((int)seconds/interval)*interval, dateinquestion.Date.AddSeconds(...)

Comment: Math.Floor instead of round, i think

Comment: I meant round towards zero, the (int) cast does the same.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the range of all your intervals to span several days, possibly a long time, you might want to express your `DateTime` values in [UNIX-seconds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) (the number of seconds since 1970-01-01). Then you just find out when your very first interval started, calculate how many seconds passed since then, and divide by two:

```
int secondsSinceFirstInterval = <currDate in UNIX time>
                                 - <start of first interval in UNIX time>;
int intervalIndex = secondsSinceFirstInterval / 2;
```

Otherwise you're better off just counting from midnight.

Answer (score 1):

Use `TimeSpan.TotalSeconds` and divide the result by the size of the interval.

```
const long intervalSize = 2;
DateTime start = new DateTime(2010, 12, 27, 12, 33, 58);

TimeSpan timeSpan = DateTime.Now - start;
long intervalInSeconds = (long)timeSpan.TotalSeconds;
long intervalNumber = 1 + intervalInSeconds / intervalSize;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 DateTime start = new DateTime(2010, 12, 31, 12, 0, 0);
 TimeSpan frameLength = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 3);
 DateTime testTime = new DateTime(2010, 12, 31, 12, 0, 4);

 int frameIndex = 0;
 while (testTime >= start)
 {
     frameIndex++;
     start = start.Add(frameLength);
 }

 Console.WriteLine(frameIndex);
```

Comment: var dt = DateTime.Now;
DateTime intervalStart = apply_the_algorythm(dt);

Comment: @skaeff: I show you most of the code you need, and figure out a direction, you can easily wrap the code in a method. Otherwise what you need to do is copying the answer, pasting to your program and running it. Do you think it's good to your skill?

Answer (score 0):

```
dates = new List<DateTime>
            {
                DateTime.Now.AddHours(-1),
                DateTime.Now.AddHours(-2),
                DateTime.Now.AddHours(-3)
            };
            dates.Sort((x, y) => DateTime.Compare(x.Date, y.Date)); 
            DateTime dateToCheck = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-120);
            int place = apply_the_algorythm(dateToCheck);
            Console.WriteLine(dateToCheck.ToString() + " is in interval :" +(place+1).ToString());

private int apply_the_algorythm(DateTime date)
        {
            if (dates.Count == 0)
                return -1;
            for (int i = 0; i < dates.Count; i++)
            {
                // check if the given date does not fall into any range.
                if (date < dates[0] || date > dates[dates.Count - 1])
                {
                    return -1;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (date >= dates[i]
                        && date < dates[i + 1])
                        return i;
                }
            }
            return dates.Count-1;
        }
```